# Will java compiler optimize a method call on a final static variable ? And what happens when it becomes dalvik code?

Tags: java, android, javac, compiler-optimization, dalvik

I have the following code

```
 float square(float val) { return val*val;}
 boolean isInCircle(final float x,final float y) {

        float squareDistance = square(cx - x) + square(cy - y);
        return squareDistance < square(RADIUS);
    }
```

where `RADIUS` is a `static` `final` `float`.

Will the java compiler optimize the call `square(RADIUS)` ?

What happens when this converted to `dalvik` code for `android` ? Will it remain optimized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizations in Java are done (as far as I know) by the [HotSpot compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) at runtime (bytecode is optimized when translated to machine code). So the answer is yes and no.

The transformed code will be equally optimized, but it depends on JVM, what will do with it. According my experience, it is highly dependent on the JVM and probably in its setting (agressivity of the optimizer). I have tried to compare running of SHA1 with loops and without on Windows JVM and Linux one. In one case the code without loops was many times faster, in the second (I think on Linux) there was only a difference about 40% of the time taken...

So it is a magic, you might give HotSpot good hints to optimize, or configure JVM, but still, it will depend on the current algorithm of JVM...

Comment: Strictly speaking optimizations are done "by the JVM". "HotSpot" is just one possible implementation of the JVM (although the most common one in the desktop/server environment).

Comment: But isn't this easy to detect at compile time ? So why can't javac optimize it ?

Comment: @GautamK: actually it's not that easy to detect. What if a derived class has a different implementation of `square()`? Then any "optimization" done by the compiler would be wrong. Also: it's a base principle of Java that the compiler itself does no real optimization, but a rather direct translation of the source to bytecode. *All* real optimization is left to the JVM which has a lot more information at its disposal during the runtime. For example: the JVM *will* know if there is a derived class and *can* then inline (or even pre-compute) the `square` call.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ok so `javac` does zero optimization ?
What about when `square` is `final` ?

Comment: @GautamK: *almost* zero. There is a very limited set of optimizations that relate to compile time constant expressions. Basically if the compiler can *guarantee* the value of an expression, then it will replace it with the pre-computed result. For example `int i = 2*3;` will compile to the same bytecode to `int i = 6;` (see [JLS §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

Comment: So if `RADIUS` is `static` and `final` and initialized at declaration time (with a constant expression), then rewriting your condition to `squareDistance < RADIUS * RADIUS` *will* result in optimized code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer : Can you post all this info as an answer please. So even if `square` is a `final` method javac will not optimize it right?

Comment: As people have pointed out, javac performs very little, if not zero, optimization. If you really want compile-time optimization, you should try some optimization tools out there. For example, you can try SOOT < http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/ >.

Answer (score 3):

The Java compiler won't do anything with that code.

The HotSpot JVM will almost certainly precompute square(RADIUS).

Android doesn't have that particular JVM.

I personally wouldn't write the square() method at all, just `return (cx-x)*(cx-x)+(cy-y)*(cy-y) < RADIUS*RADIUS;` and let the compiler/JVM battle it out from there. But then I'm a mathematician ;-)

Comment: As every Android engineer is insistent to tell everyone: Android doesn't have a JVM at all. It has "only" a [Dalvik VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I can see why ... :-|

Answer (score 2):

The Dalvik JIT compiler does in fact inline short functions, such as `square()` as defined in the question (though probably better to declare it `static`). However, I couldn't tell you off-hand whether it would definitely get inlined.

Profile the code if it matters!

Answer (score -1):

The only optimization that will happen is that the compiler will most likely "intern" the value of the static final field as a constant where it is accessed, rather than performing a field lookup at runtime.

Comment: 'Intern'? Do you mean 'inline'?